# Constrained MLE

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

How to write R-code for obtaining MLEs of a ,b and $\theta$ for the density function
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\theta(a+bx)e^{-(ax+\frac{1}{2} b x^2)}\left(1-e^{-(ax+\frac{1}{2} b x^2)}\right)^{\theta-1}
\end{equation}
where $a, b\geq 0$ such that $a+b>0$, $0<\theta\leq 1$ and $x>0$.

Comment: Hi: It's been a long time but I think that the alabama package allows for constraints such as that on $\theta$. $a$ and $b$ can be taken care of by using a transformation such as exponentiation. Check out the alabama package vignette on cran.

Comment: Presumably "$y$" means "$x$"?  What is the reason for the constraints on the parameters?  (Those can create complications for estimation and especially for obtaining measurements of uncertainty.)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to follow @mlofton 's advice about replacing `a` with `exp(loga)` and `b` with `exp(logb)`.

I think you'll also need to perform 3 optimizations with the following parameter restrictions:  (1) both `a` and `b` are positive, (2) `a` is zero and `b` is positive, and (3) `a` is positive and `b` is zero.  Then you'll pick the optimization with the largest (log) likelihood.  Below is some crude code to do so.  (I've generated a small dataset using parameters `a=1`, `b=2`, and `theta=0.5`)

```
x <- c(0.0145967, 0.104352, 0.594788, 0.174257, 0.0488928, 0.200949, 
  0.5182, 0.471903, 0.610077, 0.0111148, 0.137451, 0.11652, 0.276744, 
  0.506747, 0.481922, 0.277815, 0.0532106, 0.324047, 0.0210827, 
  0.372868, 0.531942, 0.00890716, 0.171113, 0.0342172, 0.49179, 
  0.996799, 0.0110774, 0.114063, 0.703989, 0.506975, 0.197405, 1.0114, 
  0.0901026, 0.213606, 0.262084, 0.130497, 0.2737, 0.00315518, 
  0.172291, 0.0535423, 0.740114, 0.221084, 0.603289, 0.118339, 
  0.277635, 0.335365, 0.492908, 0.00154837, 0.0392603, 0.03311, 
  0.307173, 0.446309, 0.61738, 0.789208, 0.050912, 0.320125, 0.0106654, 
  0.171508, 0.498857, 0.400646, 0.0318363, 0.00543865, 1.13852, 
  0.0172727, 0.46813, 0.439924, 0.216972, 0.465693, 0.0825827, 
  0.220415, 0.409633, 1.31055, 0.112688, 0.153516, 0.00279535, 
  0.326186, 0.34114, 0.110279, 0.0357021, 0.321345, 0.595547, 0.234129, 
  1.17108, 0.390832, 0.355294, 0.106211, 0.328448, 0.289929, 
  0.00200442, 0.274553, 0.23946, 0.00554319, 0.0976008, 0.223071, 
  0.000783119, 1.37179, 0.34531, 0.406825, 0.00406322, 0.525507)
```

Define 3 log likelihood functions.  One where $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, one where
$a = 0$ and $b > 0$, and one where $a > 0$ and $b = 0$.

```
  logL <- function(p, x) {
   n <- length(x)
   loga <- p[1]
   logb <- p[2]
   theta <- p[3]
   n*log(theta) + sum(log(exp(loga) + exp(logb)*x)) - 
   sum(exp(loga)*x + exp(logb)*x^2/2) + 
   (theta - 1)*sum(log(1 - exp(-(exp(loga)*x + exp(logb)*x^2/2))))
}

logLa0 <- function(p, x) {
   n <- length(x)
   logb <- p[1]
   theta <- p[2]
   n*log(theta) + sum(log(exp(logb)*x)) - 
   exp(logb)*sum(x^2)/2 + (theta - 1)*sum(log(1 - exp(-exp(logb)*x^2/2)))
}

logLb0 <- function(p, x) {
   n <- length(x)
   loga <- p[1]
   theta <- p[2]
   n*log(theta) + n*log(exp(loga)) - exp(loga)*sum(x) + 
   (theta - 1)*sum(log(1 - exp(-exp(loga)*x)))
}
```

Perform the 3 optimizations

```
mleab <- optim(c(log(1),log(2), 0.5), logL, x=x, method="L-BFGS-B",
  lower=c(-Inf,-Inf,0), upper=c(Inf,Inf,1), control=list(fnscale=-1) )

mlea0 <- optim(c(log(2), 0.5), logLa0, x=x, method="L-BFGS-B",
  lower=c(-Inf,0), upper=c(Inf,1), control=list(fnscale=-1) )

mleb0 <- optim(c(log(1), 0.5), logLb0, x=x, method="L-BFGS-B",
  lower=c(-Inf,0), upper=c(Inf,1), control=list(fnscale=-1) )
```

Choose the optimization with the largest log likelihood

```
if (mleab$value >= mlea0$value & mleab$value>= mleb0$value) {
   cat("MLE: a-hat = ",exp(mleab$par[1]), "b-hat = ", exp(mleab$par[2]), 
     "theta-hat = ", mleab$par[3], "\n")
}

if (mlea0$value >= mleab$value & mlea0$value>= mleb0$value) {
   cat("MLE: a-hat = 0", "b-hat = ", exp(mleab$par[1]), 
     "theta-hat = ", mleab$par[2], "\n")
}

if (mleb0$value >= mleab$value & mleb0$value>= mlea0$value) {
   cat("MLE: a-hat = ", exp(mleb0$par[1]), "b-hat = 0", 
     "theta-hat = ", mleab$par[2], "\n")
}

# MLE: a-hat =  1.275986 b-hat =  3.320629 theta-hat =  0.5962043
```

Because a parameter estimate could be on a border (either $\hat{a}=0$ or $\hat{b}=0$ (and noting @whuber 's comment), you'll probably need to estimate measures of precision with a bootstrap.